English equivalent to the Swedish idiom "Har man tagit fan i båten..."
The full idiom in swedish goes: Har man tagit fan i båten, får man ro honom i land.
The literal translation would equal something along the lines of: If you bring the devil into the boat, you have to take him to shore.
My understanding of the figurative meaning is that if you take on an unpleasant or arduous task, you're obliged to finish it. The implication being, giving up midway would cause even more problems than the initial situation.
I'm looking for an idiom in english, equivalent to this saying.

Related: Is there an English idiom for when you must commit to a course of action even if it turns out to be the wrong one? and Word/phrase for "I'm already in trouble, I might as well go further"

"It's too late to turn back now."

"You bought it, you feed it/clean it/clear up after it." Some feedback on whether this is a duplicate of the above questions would be useful.

As I understand the sense of this, it is more "If you start an action that causes trouble or difficulties, you (and only you) are the one responsible for bringing that matter to a satisfactory conclusion."

I'm not sure some of these suggestions are considered actual idioms.

There's a similarity in "He who rides the tiger must eventually dismount", which is also rendered as "He who rides a/the tiger is afraid to dismount" or simply as "He who rides a/the tiger ..." with the ominous ellipsis.
The Oxford Dictionary of Proverbs (5 ed.) gives the latter and explains:

Once a dangerous or troublesome venture is begun, the safest course is to carry it through to the end.
1875 W. Scarborough Collection of Chinese Proverbs no. 2082 He who rides a tiger is afraid to dismount. ‥Ch'i 'hu nan hsia pei.

If said to a person who has initiated the trouble, then this is given as warning guidance to them.

To my understanding, this is a very good equivalent. "In for a penny, in for a pound" seems fitting too. I like this better, though. Thanks for your contribution.
